# Playing and recording Audio simutaneouly with headset jack pin in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an iPhone application which requires to play and record Audio(I am doing this with help of AudioQueues) simultaneously. I am using headset jack pin with mic for recording and playing and the playing sound is a wav file of 5kHz.

The problem here is it's recording the sound that is playing out through output AudioQueues as well as the sound that is coming into headset mic. but I need to record only the sound that is coming through the headset mic.

I am unable to find the problem is with the headset jack pins(I have tested with lot off headset jack pins) or any programming settings like AudioSessions. the same is with the AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder too.

Can anyone tell the problem and some help and suggestions would very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the proper 3-ring-plus-tip mike adapter?  It should look like a zebra: http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/public/_lMbkhC-RNOfLBVTQABxsqJUoxjTvT-XYcWlwgHgVtOr-5A9UaYsc6NhHoTonK1PE1DYIte6QPsb1IdcUb67tmwkAnsRKu0i797ymQxtiySwNyzsJao3zSPytf_ckgQ

Comment: Yes, I have 3-ring-plus-tip mike adapter, through which recording the sound is happening but playing sound also recording. through jack pin it should only record the sound that is coming through jack pin's mic. right?

Comment: I think there's a setting in the sound stuff, either on the mike side or the earphone side, that "bridges" between the two.  I don't recall the details, though.  Also, if your adapter is incorrectly constructed it could cause "bleed" between the two.  The wiring of the plug is a hair illogical.  IIRC, the ring farthest from the tip is the mike, and the one next to that the common ground (but the chart is on the internet in several locations to check that).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to pump the input sound using external amplifier/ mixer. Mic alone will not work properly. If you increase the recording volume in your pc you will hear louder hissing sound and at the same time it will continue to record the playback sound. So the only solution is use external source (amply/mixer) to raise the level of the input mic.